# What method for PI to track time spent on grant project?

Tags: funding, time-management

What methods do PIs out there use to track time spent on a funded grant project for reporting purposes with the funding agency?

I'm specifically interested in the USA, for reference, if it varies internationally.

Comment: Prjoect management in the world is based on propertiary tools and people copying&pasting numbers from whatever format to a spreadsheets software. A software that is always at the forefront of the computational resources, i.e. a software that indipendently from how new is your computer, it will run always at the same pace: MS Excel :) .

Comment: At least for the NIH and NSF, that level of reporting is not required. You say, "I spent 0.6 person months on this project" and you did.

Comment: Are you looking for a program to log times spent on particular tasks by particular people?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Research administrator in the US here.  Tracking depends on many things, e.g., sponsor policies and reporting, institutional policies on effort certification, etc.

In general, the method I use for PIs to help estimate, is I ask "how many hours/week do you spend on this project?"  I can also do the same with the interval as a month if that it easier.  Sometimes estimating "one day a month" makes sense, and then we extrapolate over 12 months to get to 12 days, i.e., roughly half a month (although you could be more precise at 0.40 if you need to).

When there are no time sheets, it's all a rough estimate.  When it comes to RPPRs (progress reports) for NSF and NIH, a month is roughly 160 hours.  So if hours is helpful to use, you can do that too.  If you spent about 5 hours a month, then in the course of a year, it's 60 hours, and rounds down to 0 months on the report.

You need to check with your local research administrator for help with understanding your salary distribution.  Those rules are always institution-specific.  Overall you should be looking at the total amounts that go on your current and pending/other support documents and make sure you have a cohesive narrative about how you allocate your time.  Funding agencies definitely care about what effort amounts you indicate on those documents to determine if you are overcommitted or not.